# Swift Running Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got this error after running my app, can anyone tell me what caused it?

> 2017-07-30 16:42:38.066 MyDiscountApp[1354:264950] *** Terminating app. due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key button.'

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions seeking debugging help must include relevant code to be considered on-topic on SO. See [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the relevant code in your question. Are you sure you set up both corner radius and clipsToBounds = true for the UIImageView as well and not just for the collection view cell?

Comment: @DávidPásztor please edit the above comment , I think you copy pasted it from some other place

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard/nib file of the `ViewController` class, you have assigned an object with the name button to the class, but in the `ViewController` class, you have not defined the button or you may have defined it but then deleted it and forgot to remove the connection from nib/storyboard.

Comment: I don't know that before that there is a relation in the storyboard, I removed the relation and it works

Comment: @MalikTurk: happy that you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

You probably made an `Outlet` (connection of the button between your Storyboard and `ViewController` class) and then deleted the outlet in the code.

You also need to delete the connection in Storyboard. See the screenshot below to see how to do it:

[image: Screenshot of Storyboard]